# Running one thread 10,000 times

Tags: jmeter

How to run a thread group for a given number of times, eg. 10,000 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) where number of iterations are in your control (you can define) instead of scheduled time (there is no control over no. of iterations, once time is completed, JMeter stops the test). So, I suggest using Loop Controller.

When you ran the test for 5 mins, it might be the reason that scheduled time got completed so stopped the test, hence next 2 requests are not sent.

Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and observe the behaviour. Once debugging is done, remove the listener as it consumes a lot of resources.

Comment: So I tried by giving Loop count in the thread group as 5. In view result tree, i can see that it is picking up all the three HTTP Requests in the first loop, but in the rest, it is just picking the first one. I tried Loop control and it also behaves the same way. Running all 3 requests in the first loop and for the rest picks only the first one.

Comment: if you use `loop count`, all the requests in thread group will run for the given count. If you use `Loop Controller`, only the requests inside of it will run for the given count in Controller. please add screenshot of yor configuration.

Comment: I want the whole thread group to run in loop. Sorry I am not sure how to add screenshot here.

Comment: Click can `edit` link under the question, there you can see image icon. click on it and upload the screenshot

Comment: added screenshot!

Comment: Thanks. As you want whole thread group to run for given number of times, configure `loop count` value to `5` and try. It should run all the HTTP requests inside that Thread Group for 5 time. If any while/loop controller is part of the Thread Group, then it multiplies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133290/discussion-between-naveen-and-jane).

Comment: yes I tried that and as I said above, it is running all the HTTP requests in  the first loop but only the first request for the rest of the loops. I will post the result screenshot